# What information does single sign on save

Tags: facebook, single-sign-on

I am developing a mobile app and want to know what specific information the facebook single sign on saves using the provided code:

```
public class MyGreatActivity extends Activity {

    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("YOUR_APP_ID");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

I want to pull information from the user from facebook that will fill in fields to make registration quicker for new users using my app. What specific information can be pulled for this purpose? Any insight is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just determine what permissions your user has already authorized and that will tell you what information you can read without asking for permission.

You check permission via the Graph API

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions
```

or via FQL

```
SELECT email,publish_stream FROM permissions WHERE uid = me()
```